# Binding a button press to a Backbone view event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a very simple form

```
  <div id="formQuickRegister">
      <form>
        <fieldset>
          <input id="inputUserName" type="text" placeholder="Username"><br>
          <input id="inputUserEmail" type="text" placeholder="Email"><br>
          <input id="inputUserPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
          <button id="btnRegisterNow">Register Now</button>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
  </div>
```

and I have a view on Backbone that renders it and have an event attached

```
define(['text!templates/index.html', 'account'], function (templateIndex, account){
    var viewIndex = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#content'),

        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(templateIndex);
        },

        events: {
            'submit form': 'register'
        },

        register: function () {
            event.preventDefault();

            userToRegister = new account.userModel;

            userToRegister.set('username', $('#formQuickRegister fieldset input#inputUserName').val() );
            userToRegister.set('email', $('#formQuickRegister fieldset input#inputUserEmail').val() );
            userToRegister.set('password', $('#formQuickRegister fieldset input#inputUserPassword').val() );

            account.quickRegister ( userToRegister);
        }
    });

    return new viewIndex;
});
```

If in the events I look for the "Submit Form" I can capture the event and process the code.
What I would like to do in the events is to be able to catch the click on the submit button of the form as in example:

```
events: { 'click input#btnRegisterNow': 'register'}
```

but this example does not work, and I have tried several sintaxis without success.
Would you please point me the sintax to catch the click on that #btnRegisterNow button?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. It should just be:

```
events: {
    'click #btnRegisterNow': 'register'
}
```

In your template, `btnRegisterNow` is an HTML `<button>` but your selector is looking for an `<input>` tag with the ID of `btnRegisterNow`. You *could* also use `button#btnRegisterNow` but since IDs are supposed to be unique in the document, putting tag name in your selector is redundant.

Comment: I knew I was for sure missing a very simple thing. Thank you very much, this worked like I wanted.